# Xcode: Lazy variable value not available in debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

Why is a lazy variable not available for inspection in the Xcode debugger?

```
var d: Date? {
   return Date()
}

let date = d
// Set breakpoint here
```

At the breakpoint the variable inspector in Xcode shows value `Date?` for variable `date`. When trying to print the description of the variable the lldb console prints:

```
Printing description of date:
(Date?) date = <variable not available>
```

`Build Settings > Optimization Level` is set to `-Onone` for `debug` and the scheme's `Build Configuration` is set to `Debug`.

Comment: Even at -Onone the swift compiler does some level of optimization, and so it sometimes loses debug information for variables, particularly if they aren't used in a substantial way.  I couldn't make a simple example where I couldn't see `date` with the Xcode-9.0 swift compiler, though I could make one where it lost `d`.  The swift compiler folks treat variable disappearance at -Onone as a bug, so if you are seeing this it would be good to report it. Since this sort of bug is generally sensitive to some particular detail of your code, you'll need to provide an example for them to take action.

Comment: BTW, a bunch of bugs of this sort were fixed between Xcode 8.x and 9.0 so it would also be worth trying out 9.0 if you aren't using that already.